# Responsive background being squished in portrait mobile

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive-design

I'm having a problem using responsive backgrounds. http://poppykeith.co.uk/index.html looks correct on computer browsers and in landscape on a mobile browser, however when viewed on a mobile (im using iOS) in portrait, the image is squished to fit the screen.

How would I go about making the image just zoom in in portrait mode and not stretch?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you wrote almost works, but the `min-width:1024px` and the `width:100%` rules are conflicting with each other and causing the squishing effect you see. Basically, `width` trumps `min-width`.

The real technique you want to use is to set that image as a background on the body element, and then use `background-size:cover` to make the browser load it appropriately

```
body { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Details: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: http://www.teknocat.org/blog/web-development/show/6/mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk

It talks about how Mobile Safari likes to scale down large images.